# How to find the probability distribution and we are given the expected value and variance?

Tags: probability

The question is:

A random variable $Y$ can only take values in $\lbrace−10, 0, 10 \rbrace.$ The expected value of $Y$ is $0$ and its variance is $80.$ Find the probability distribution of $Y.$

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
It works for your case of 3 variables because you have 3 unknowns and but you also have 3 equations, one from normalization of probabilities, one from mean, one from variance.